# colorBox watermark in images

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

So I was looking for how to add a watermark with colorBox to the images and I found in the first results of google an older colorBox group with the next answer:

> Jack Moore
>
> 10/3/09
>
> Ok, this should be easy to do.  I appended a bit of HTML using the
>   'cbox_complete' event, but you could easily put that same code as
>   colorbox's callback without using the event.  Here's the JS:

```
$().bind('cbox_complete', function(){
     $('#cboxLoadedContent').append("<div id='protect' />");
});
```

> and in my stylesheet I added the following style for 'protected':

```
#protect{background:url(transparent.gif) 0 0 repeat; width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
```

But that solution load the water mark to all the cbox, since .bind('cbox_complete') it's a global variable, so I made a little fix to work just with specific windows or links I want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gallery").colorbox({
        width:"800",
        onComplete:function(){ $('#cboxLoadedContent').append("<div id='protect'></div>"); }
    });
});
```

And now its working, hope this help anyone because I didnt find this in other site, but its some how in one of the examples...

Now my Question, when load the image, the watermark appears in the top-left... I want it in the bottom-rigth.

I already try change the

```
brackground-position: right bottom;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
```

with and without

```
postition: absolute;
```

and I just can make it work, any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Size of your transparent.gif in pixel?

Comment: I can't because, the web images are in different sizes each one, so I can't define a size for the transparent.gif, the css have to be variable.

Comment: I mean if you want it to be in the bottom-right, make sure that the transparent.gif is smaller than the gallery width itself (800px) and you should not set it repeat, it should be no-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create fiddle if it meets your need here http://jsfiddle.net/aanred/DSXHt/. The CSS style for the #protect is like this:

```
#protect {
    background:url(watermark.gif) bottom right no-repeat; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    left:0;
}​
```

ps: if background can't be loaded just change it with any other image since I only set it to image I found on the net.

Comment: Thank's, it works like a charm, I just add a line:

`margin:-27px 0px 0px 0px;`

To re-arange the logo because the default color box have a bar of 30px wiht the info of the picture!!!

But thank you again!